# Bottom padding not working on div

Tags: html, css, padding

```css
#Text {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    width: 750px;
    height: 750px;
    padding-bottom: 2cm;
}
```

```html
<div id="Text">
  I am groot!
</div>
```

This is what it looks like right now-

[Right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21NdB.jpg)

Comment: Run the snippet based on your code and update the question with what exactly is the problem there. I can't find any...

Comment: You are giving it an explicit height, so you won't see much of the bottom padding. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: it's working fine. the padding is the green http://i.imgur.com/KqL0rY6.png

Answer (score 0):

You have a high altitude. You can remove the height and then run padding or give more than 750px, instead of 2cm.

```
#Text {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    width: 750px;
    height: 750px;
    padding-bottom: 1200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

or

```
#Text {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    width: 750px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

At you it also works.